# Not understanding how driver unable to locate element

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

Here is the website: https://seekingalpha.com/news/3580581-docusign-eps-beats-0_02-beats-on-revenue

I am trying to webscrape the EPS, EPS beat, GEPS GEPS beat, and revenue revenue beat.

```
List1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/text()[2]""")
```

This returns unable to locate element.

Also this does not work

```
List1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div[3]""")
```

I don't think it is due to the website being loaded. I put time.sleep to be 10 seconds and it also did not work. I am not sure how I navigate through the website to get to the list that has the information I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print desired texts you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- To print *DocuSign (NASDAQ:DOCU): Q1 Non-GAAP EPS of $0.12 beats by $0.02; GAAP EPS of -$0.26 misses by $0.03.*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://seekingalpha.com/news/3580581-docusign-eps-beats-0_02-beats-on-revenue')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-id='content-container']/ul/li"))).text)
  ```
- To print *Q1 Non-GAAP EPS of $0.12*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-id='content-container']/ul/li")))).strip())
  ```
- To print *beats by $0.02*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-id='content-container']/ul/li")))).strip())
  ```
- To print *GAAP EPS of -$0.26*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-id='content-container']/ul/li")))).strip())
  ```
- To print *misses by $0.03*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-id='content-container']/ul/li")))).strip())
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Very strange issue. I was able to get the data with the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)
driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/news/3580581-docusign-eps-beats-0_02-beats-on-revenue")
time.sleep(40)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 400)") 
time.sleep(20)
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/section[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
for dat in data:
    print(dat.text)
```

It appears that the page does not fully load unless the user does some scrolling, perhaps for optimization purposes. Hopefully this works for you as well!

Comment: Thanks, the real problem in my case was that I forgot to switch tabs. I went onto seekingalpha website. Clicked on a link and did not switch to that new tab. Once I fixed it onto the correct tab then things worked again.